# service fabric actor timeout

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a service fabric OWIN based API which is calling a service fabric actor.
API waits for the actor to complete the work before returning the response. Sometimes the actor can take long time to complete.

The default timeout for Actor is 5 mins and I've tried to increase the operation timeout using :

```
[assembly: FabricTransportServiceRemotingProvider(MaxMessageSize = 1073741824, OperationTimeoutInSeconds = 600)]
```

in both the API and the actor. But it is throwing timeout error exactly after 5 mins. is there any other way I can increase the timeout of the service fabric service/actor?

below is the error I'm receiving at API end:

```
"This can happen if message is dropped when service is busy or its long running operation and taking more time than configured Operation Timeout."
```

Answer (score 0):

What if the job takes even longer than expected? Have you considered making this asynchronous / event driven?

For example:

1. Call `BeginProcessing`, schedule a Reminder inside the Actor. Return a Job-token.
2. Reminder fires, processing starts.
3. Processing completes.
4. Notify caller (using SignalR or similar), or expose a `GetJobProgress` endpoint on a `JobMonitorActor`. Use Job-token for correlation.

Comment: The problem is -- even if you do your work in a reminder -- calls to the actor will timeout while it's processing inside that reminder. -- Unfortunately there's no REAL `Tell` command (or Mailbox) in Service Fabric Reliable Actors, so, you can't send them messages unless they are completely free and doing nothing. -- It's a huge short coming of this implementation. :(